# How to draw a true pie chart?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.5cm,linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1)
\SpecialCoor
\degrees[100]
%%%%
\rput(.05;8.5){\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{0}{17}
\rput(1.2;8){\psframebox*{\small 17 \%}}}
%%%%
\rput(.05;! 17 12.5 add){\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{17}{42}
\rput(1.2;29){\psframebox*{\Large 25 \%}}}
%%%%%
\rput(.05;! 42 8 add){\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{42}{58}
\rput(1.2;50){\psframebox*{\Large 16 \%}}}
%%%%
\rput(.05;! 58 12.5 add){\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{58}{83}
\rput(1.2;71){\psframebox*{\Large 25 \%}}}
%%%%
\rput(.05;! 83 8.5 add){\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{83}{100}
\rput(1.2;92){\psframebox*{\Large 17 \%}}}
\psdot(0,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, it is skewed. What can I do?

Comment: I don't really see the problem. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Bernard It mean they should be located on a circle.

Comment: What should be on a circle, which is not?

Comment: You can see around (0,0). It seems slightly wrong.

Comment: @Bernard, I'm not sure, but visually looks like different line width or maybe not exploded by same amount, so the curved curves are not over a circle.

Comment: You mean the centre of the pie chart? That seems to be linked to your \pswedges notbeing  centred at the origin. Why didn't you use the  `psChart` environment?

Comment: @Bernard Because psChart only use **color** !

Comment: Ad a **true** pie chart doesn't use colours? :o) OK, I'll try to see if I find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The centre of the wedges are all different, so the corresponding arcs, geometrically cannot be on the same circle. The closer these centres are from the origin, the closer the arcs are from an ideal circle,. So I decreased the distance of the centres from the origin, and cheated a bit with the polar angles of some of them. Please see if it's OK for you:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5cm,linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1)
\SpecialCoor
\degrees[100]
%%%%
\rput(.03;8.5){\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{0}{17}
\rput(1.2;8){\psframebox*{\small 17 \%}}}
%%%%
\rput(.03;29){\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{17}{42}
\rput(1.2;29){\psframebox*{\Large 25 \%}}}
%%%%%
\rput(.03;50){\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{42}{58}
\rput(1.2;50){\psframebox*{\Large 16 \%}}}
%%%%
\rput(.03;70.5){\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{58}{83}
\rput(1.2;71){\psframebox*{\Large 25 \%}}}
%%%%
\rput(.03;90){\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray]{2}{83}{100}
\rput(1.2;92){\psframebox*{\Large 17 \%}}}
\psdot(0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \rput(.046;8.5)...\rput(.04;! 42 8 add)...\rput(.043;! 83 8.5 add). Thanks for your explanation ...

Answer (score 3):

It cannot be exactly on an outer circle!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=1.5cm,linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.1,-2.1)(2.1,2.1)
\degrees[100]%
%%%%
\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray](0.05;8.5){2}{0}{17}
    \rput*(1.2;8){\small 17 \%}%
%%%%
\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray](0.05;29.5){2}{17}{42}
    \rput*(1.2;29){\Large 25 \%}%
%%%%%
\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray](0.05;50){2}{42}{58}
    \rput*(1.2;50){\Large 16 \%}
%%%%
\pswedge[fillstyle=hlines,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray](0.05;70.5){2}{58}{83}
    \rput*(1.2;71){\Large 25 \%}
%%%%
\pswedge[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,hatchcolor=gray](0.05;-8.5){2}{83}{100}
    \rput*(1.2;92){\Large 17 \%}
\psdot(0,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]